# Unable to change URxvt's color

Tags: rxvt, x-resources

I added this line in .Xresources:

```
urxvt.background: #0f0f0f
```

And ran `xrdb -merge .Xresources`. However, for some reason, the terminal is set to the color when it is launched, but as soon as the $PS1 tag appears, the background is reset to black. I tried using URxvt*background but it didn't work either.

Here is my $PS1

```
reset=$(tput sgr0)
bold=$(tput bold)
    PS1="[\[$bold\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\[$reset\]]\$ "
```

However, it is normally handled by powerline-shell. Though, when I disable it, it still resets the color.

EDIT: I modified it, and now it looks like this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"
else
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"
    #Default setting
    #PS1="[\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}"
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

I added the whole block of code in, just in case. The color is still resetting unfortunately.

UPDATE : I managed to find out that the background color is the same as the first color in the palette. Is there anyway I could override that?

Comment: What is your `$PS1`? In which shell?

Comment: Updated the question with the $PS1, and the shell is Bash.

Comment: What's the value of `$TERM`, and the output of `tput sgr0 | cat -A`?

Comment: $TERM says `rxvt-unicode-256color: command not found`, and `tput sgr0 | cat -A` says `^[[m^[(B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem is -

Firstly - urxvt doesn't let you change the background color if the transparency is turned on. It automatically sets it to black.

Secondly - a different app, called pywal, was setting my colorscheme. I simply didn't know it was also setting the background, and I didn't check beforehand. That was my mistake.

If I had any tips to give - it's to check everything that may be messing with your colorscheme, and disable urxvt's transparency, using a compositing manager instead to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem, solution for me was to disable transparency in ~/.Xresources

```
URxvt.transparent: false
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> reset=$(tput sgr0)
> ```

Well there you go.  You are using the `sgr0` capability which is *defined* as resetting all attributes and colours.

> ```
> … \033[00m … \033[00m …
> ```

You are even hardwiring it in the prompt several times over.

Do not do that, then.

terminfo lacks a capability for obtaining the reset bold sequence.  But since you are hardwiring ECMA-48 control sequences *anyway* you might as well hardwire the ECMA-48:1984 control sequence CSI `2` `2` `m` (i.e. `\033[22m`) to *just* turn off boldface.  Unicode RXVT supports it.

Comment: I forgot that's what that particular bit did, let me try to modify it.

Comment: I changed the $PS1 and made it look like above, but the effect is still happening unfortunately.